# Как обновлять библиотеки в микросервисах?

Tags: javascript, java, kotlin

В общем, такая ситуация. Есть n-ное количество микросервисов и отдельный сервис, который представляет собой совокупность собственных библиотек. Соответственно, меняя что-то в какой-либо своей библиотеке, после инкремента ее версии надо обновлять эту версию во всех микросервисах, в которых эта библиотека подключена. Но что, если, допустим, библиотеку по факту надо обновить только в 3 микросервисах, а в остальных в принципе не надо (потому что изменения в этой библиотеке не повлияют на них)? Скорее всего это не особо правильно, но может есть какие-то "паттерны" на этот счет?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что он по сути дублирует предыдущий вопрос [Нумерация релизов для сервисов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1515684/)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Нумерация релизов для сервисов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1515684/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: Обновлять надо все сервисы, которые используют библиотеку. Исключение только мажорные версии - у них может не быть обратной совместимости, потому их автоматом не обновляют.

Answer (score 0):

"потому что изменения в этой библиотеке не повлияют на них" - значит можно и обновлять, тогда обновляйте в них тоже и не придумывайте себе препятсвия